# Error PLS-00201 Identifier 'REG_PACK.DELUSER' must be declared

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm getting an error stated above.
I've tried granting the user to execute but no luck.

Here's my SQL code:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY reg_pack AS PROCEDURE ADDUSER( c_fname IN user_profile.firstname%type, c_lname IN user_profile.lastname%type, c_cnum  IN user_profile.contactno%type, c_dob IN USER_PROFILE.DOB%type, c_address IN user_profile.address%type, c_city IN user_profile.city%type, c_state IN user_profile.state%type, c_country IN user_profile.country%type, c_email IN user_profile.emailid%type, c_password IN user_profile.password%type, c_usertype IN user_profile.usertype%type, c_username IN user_profile.username%type) IS BEGIN   INSERT INTO USER_PROFILE (userid,firstname   ,lastname,contactno,dob,address,city,state   ,country,emailid,password,usertype,username)    VALUES   (userid_seq.NEXTVAL, c_fname, c_lname, c_cnum,    c_dob, c_address, c_city, c_state, c_country,    c_email, c_password, c_usertype, c_username); END ADDUSER;

    PROCEDURE DELUSER(c_id IN user_profile.userid%type) IS BEGIN   DELETE FROM USER_PROFILE    WHERE user_profile.userid = c_id; END DELUSER;

    PROCEDURE SELECTUSER(c_id IN user_profile.userid%type, c_fname OUT user_profile.firstname%type, c_lname OUT user_profile.lastname%type, c_cnum OUT user_profile.contactno%type, c_dob OUT USER_PROFILE.DOB%type, c_address OUT user_profile.address%type, c_city OUT user_profile.city%type, c_state OUT user_profile.state%type, c_country OUT user_profile.country%type, c_email OUT user_profile.emailid%type, c_password OUT user_profile.password%type, c_usertype OUT user_profile.usertype%type, c_username OUT user_profile.username%type) AS   BEGIN
SELECT FIRSTNAME ,LASTNAME ,CONTACTNO ,DOB ,ADDRESS ,CITY ,STATE ,   COUNTRY ,EMAILID ,PASSWORD ,USERTYPE ,USERNAME   INTO   c_fname, c_lname, c_cnum, c_dob, c_address, c_city,   c_state, c_country, c_email, c_password, c_usertype, c_username   
FROM USER_PROFILE    
WHERE user_profile.userid = c_id;    END SELECTUSER; 
END reg_pack;
```

As you can see there are three procedures namely `DELUSER`, `ADDUSER` and `SELECTUSER`. I'm using `JDBC` to execute these queries, the `ADDUSER` query worked but the other two returned `PLS-00201`.

Here's my JAVA code:
For insert:

```
    sql2 = "{call REG_PACK.ADDUSER(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
    callable = con.prepareCall(sql2);
    callable.setString(1, fname);
    callable.setString(2, lname);
    callable.setString(3, cnum);
    callable.setString(4, dob);
    callable.setString(5, address);
    callable.setString(6, city);
    callable.setString(7, state);
    callable.setString(8, country);
    callable.setString(9, email);
    callable.setString(10, password);
    callable.setString(11, utype);
    callable.setString(12, username);
    callable.executeQuery();
```

for delete:

```
int userID = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
System.out.println(userID);
try{
    String sqlDelete = "{CALL REG_PACK.DELUSER(?)}";
    callable = con.prepareCall(sqlDelete);
    callable.setInt(1, userID);
    callable.executeQuery();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "User deleted!");

}catch(SQLException e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Are they declared in the package header, as opposed to only in the package body?

Comment: I've declared them in the package header as well as the package body @JP Moresmau

Comment: I've also tried to execute it in a ``pl/sql`` block and it works. Only in``jdbc`` it fails.

Comment: call in lower case? (call instead of CALL)?

Comment: Still the same :( @JPMoresmau

Comment: What user owns the `REG_PACK` package?  In your JDBC code, are you connecting as that user or as a different user?

Comment: My ``mydbms`` user owns the package and the one who uses it.